# I tried to post a question but the preview became garbled

Tags: discussion, formatting

newbie here !

I pasted a text with my question  and several parts of code and tried  to mark them, and posted it but when I edited it to correct a typo the marking was distorted and several codes became a one long code. When I tried to sort it out my text got several lines in Bold with larger fonts.

I edited again deleted the whole thing  and pasted a fresh clip but it showed the some distortions that had appeared in the first version.

I then deleted the whole thing and wrote a short message explaining that I would try again in a new 'uncontaminated' post.

When I asked a new question the title of the old question was already there, and the  same problems with fonts occurred even when I pasted a different text.

I then edited the old question to change its title   so that a new post would not be 'contaminated'. But it was.

This post with a new title and no code looks alright.

What must I do?

Comment: I rolled back your edits to the original question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/732625/70524 Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help on how to format properly.